# Переливающийся текст при наведении

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

Подскажите как сделать эффект переливания цвета у текста при наведении?
Эффект должен быть похож на волну, пересекающую текст слева на право. В учебнике html не нашел как сделать.
Спасибо тем, кто поможет!

```css
.text {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #13678a;
}

.text:hover {
  color: #b59b9b
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Text</div>
```

Comment: [Вот отличный пример](https://codepen.io/miketricking/pen/dYwepq)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Такое нужно было?

```css
.text {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #13678a;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.text:hover {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(-75deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) 30%, #000 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) 70%);
  -webkit-mask-size: 200%;
  animation: wave 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave {
  from {
    -webkit-mask-position: 150%;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-mask-position: -50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

### Решение SVG + CSS

При наведении `begin="svg1.mouseenter"` заполнение многоцветным градиентом слева-направо.
При покидании курсора `begin="svg1.mouseleave"` возврат заполнения градиентом

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="280.089px" height="280.089px" viewBox="0 0 280.089 280.089" style="border:1px solid">
    <polygon class="wdgreyAnim" fill="url(#largeGradient)" points="49.498,91.095 73.592,188.992 101.322,188.992 115.607,135.212 129.191,188.994 150.898,188.994 177.931,110.705 195.294,167.986 162.38,167.986 155.238,188.994 230.591,188.994 199.076,91.095 158.711,91.211 141.919,136.94 132.27,91.095 103.699,91.095 91.522,142.325 79.75,91.095 " />
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="largeGradient" x2="0%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#4c7eaf"></stop>
            <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#4a8eac"></stop>
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#46a5a7"></stop>
            <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#53bfac"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#828282"></stop>
            <animate attributeName="x2" dur="2s" begin="svg1.mouseenter" from="0%" to="100%" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" /> 
            <animate attributeName="x2" dur="2s" begin="svg1.mouseleave" from="100%" to="0%" repeatCount="1"   />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Двухцветный градиент слева-направо и назад

```html
<style>
.crc1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
</style>
<svg class="the-svg" width="400px" height="200" viewBox="-20 -20 200 200">
  
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#24bed2"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#FF00AE"/>
    <animate attributeName="x1" dur="4s" values="0;400;400;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <text class="crc1" x="50" y="50" r="50" font-size="72px" font-weight="900">Text</text>
</svg>
```

Переход при наведении с одной пары градиентов на другую пару градиентов

```css
.txt1 {
  fill: url('#grad1');
}
.txt1 ~ defs stop {
  transition: 1s;
}

.txt1 ~ defs stop:first-child {
  stop-color: dodgerblue;
}
.txt1:hover ~ defs stop:last-child {
  stop-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<svg class="the-svg" width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
    <text class="txt11" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/> 
   <rect width="100%" height="50%" fill="#212121" />
  <text class="txt1" font-size="120" font-family="serif" font-weight="600" x="10" y="100" >Text </text>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1"
      x1="0"
      x2="0"
      y1="200"
      y2="0"
      gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="35%" stop-color="#FF1B1B"/>
      <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#FF1B1B"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Заполнение цветом с помощью JS

```js
function setProgress(amt)
{
  amt = (amt < 0) ? 0 : (amt > 1) ? 1 : amt;
  document.getElementById("stop1").setAttribute("offset", amt);
  document.getElementById("stop2").setAttribute("offset", amt);
}

val = 0;
colorTimeout();

function colorTimeout() {
  setProgress(val);
  val += 0.008;
  if (val <= 1) {
    setTimeout(colorTimeout, 45);
  }
}
```

```css
text {
  font: san-serif;
  font-size: 120px;
  fill: url(#progress);
}
```

```html
<svg width="800" height="150">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="progress">
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0" stop-color="purple"/>
      <stop id="stop2" offset="0" stop-color="grey"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <text x="20" y="120">Цветной текст</text>
</svg>
```

### Вращение цветной градиентной полосы

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;

}
#txt {
font-size:64px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<svg width="545" height="80" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
        <animate attributeName="x1" values="0;0;1;1;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y1" values="0;1;1;0;0" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="x2" values="1;1;0;0;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="y2" values="1;0;0;1;1" keyTimes="0;.25;.5;.75;1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="yellow"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="green"/>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <text id="txt" x="20" y="50"  fill="url(#Gradient)">Цветной Текст</text/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Чего здесь только не было))) Здорово!!!

Answer (score 5):

Зачем вам эта вырвиглазная хрень?

```css
.text {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #13678a;
}

.text:hover {
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black, red, blue, green, magenta, cyan, yellow, black);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  background-size: 300px 300px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  animation: bp 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes bp {
  from {
    background-position-x: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position-x: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Text</div>
```

Comment: Префикс **-webkit** к `background-clip`, [говорят](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip), надо.

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov ладно

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать **Splitting.js** .

Посмотреть пример можно здесь: https://codepen.io/Rate12-the-sans/pen/qBgLOPd

```
.text-block {
  animation: slide-in 1s both;
  animation-delay: calc( .25s + (80ms * var(--char-index)));
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

---

```
<div class="text-block">Some text</div>
```

---

```
Splitting();
```

В JS для этого пишется лишь одна строчка, всё остальное в CSS-файле.